# How to show a List <string> within an Object in the GridView BoundFeild DataField asp.net webforms.

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, gridview, webforms

I have a JSON string in database stored in one column like this:

[Image JSON Text stored within Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kyoFj.jpg)

I then retrieve this piece of string from database and Deserialize it into a Config Object in my aspx.cs file.

From there I create a List of Component Objects by Iterating through the deserialized Config object and adding it into the List. (As Config Object will have multiple Component Objects stored).

I then want to display my List of Component Objects in the browser using GridView control. I am able to get all the properties displayed except for one of the properties of Component Object which is a List of String.

I want to be able to display the whole List within one cell (for each object). However it shows me like this:

[Image of GridView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7DOU8.jpg)

As you can see in the Image of GridView above under the Role column it doesnt show me the values within the roles List.

How can I get that to be shown?

My code for creating the List of Components and binding it to data source is:

```
List<Component> componentListForGridView = new List<Component>();
        foreach(Component comp in DeserializedObject.Component)
        {
            componentListForGridView.Add(comp);
        }

        GridView1.DataSource = componentListForGridView;
        GridView1.DataBind();
```

My code in aspx to show the table is:

```
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" AutoGenerateColumns="false"  runat="server">
        <columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="id" HeaderText="ID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="visible" HeaderText="Visible" />
             <asp:BoundField DataField="roles" HeaderText="Role" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="childControls.controlList[0].id" HeaderText="ControlId" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="childControls.controlList[0].src" HeaderText="ControlSrc"/>
        </columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

The structure of my Component class is:

```
 public class Component
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string visible { get; set; }


    public List<string> roles { get; set; }
    public ChildControls childControls { get; set; }

}
```

Where the roles List is created by splitting a comma separated string value from a text box on the form.

The JSON text is pasted below for reference:

```
{ "Component": [
{
  "id": "companyEmployee",
  "visible": "true",
  "roles": [
    "manager",
    "employee"
  ],
  "childControls": {
    "controlList": [
      {
        "id": "compLogo",
        "src": "content/images/epharma_logo__u40.png#"
      }
    ]
  }
},
{
  "id": "noman",
  "visible": "false",
  "roles": [
    "manager",
    "employee",
    "employer"
  ],
  "childControls": {
    "controlList": [
      {
        "id": "test",
        "src": "content/images/epharma_logo__u40.png#"
      }
    ]
  }
} ]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here what you can try:

Create a method in code behind for rendering the list of roles

```
protected string DisplayRoles(Component component) {
   string displayOutput = String.Empty;

   if(component!=null) {
      foreach(string role in component.roles) {
        displayOutput+=role + "<br/>";
    }
  }

    return displayOutput;
}
```

Use GridView ItemTemplate field instead of Bounded Field and call the method created in step 1:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Role">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%# DisplayRoles((Component)Container.DataItem) %>
            </ItemTemplate>

        </asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: Thanks, it does the job for now.